# $js in select dropdown in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have a js in a folder js.  I call the file in the header.
I have the next code in my view:

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('mydropdown',$options) ?>
```

I need to pass the paramether $js, could you help me with the syntax?

```
$js = 'id="shirts" onChange="display(this,\'id1\',\'id2\');"';


<?php echo form_dropdown('mydropdown',$options, $js) ?>
```

When I see the source code of my dropdown I can't see the id="shirts", then I believe that the function javascript is not recognized.

What's my error.  My codeigniter version is 2.0.

Thanks.

Comment: `$js` needs to be the 4th parameter.  It's `form_dropdown('name', $options, 'selected', $js);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javascript should be the **fourth** parameter to this call. So add a `null` parameter in the third (which is for the selected value of the dropdown):

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('mydropdown',$options, null, $js) ?>
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html